# How to fill a 2 dimensional array's row with random numbers from Enumerable.Range list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, enumerable

I'm trying to fill each row of a 2 dimensional array with 6 random numbers from an Enumerable.Range list that contains 45 numbers. Each time 6 numbers have been entered into the specific row of the array, they are removed from the list. The problem is that each row of the array uses the same list until there are no numbers left in it. How do I reset the list for each row?

This is what I have so far:

```
    static void InitMatrix(int[,] mat)
{

    List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 45).ToList();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if(mat.GetLength(0)< mat.GetLength(1))

        for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            int index = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count );
            mat[i, j] = numbers[index];
            numbers.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to reset the list each time, declare it inside the for loop. Somethig like `List<int> numbers = new List<int>;...numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 45).ToList();`

Comment: @Eminem I think you've got it. Post that as an answer and I'll give you +1.

Comment: @TimS. I'm too slow for these guys.. :)

Comment: Note that two of the answers are different - one will create a new list even if the `if statement` is false, and the other won't.

Comment: @Eminem I put my List declaration inside the If statement because you only need the list for true outcomes of the If statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the list declaration to below the first (row) loop. That way whenever the loop moves to the next row the list is reinitialized / refreshed if you will...

```
static void InitMatrix(int[,] mat)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 45).ToList();

        if(mat.GetLength(0)< mat.GetLength(1))
        {
           for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
           {
               int index = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count );
               mat[i, j] = numbers[index];
               numbers.RemoveAt(index);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error here, the "if(mat...) inside the loop doesn't have brackets or anything under it. I know its in the original code but it wouldn't work there either.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's not a syntax error, but it is poor formatting. The `if` statement here applies to the `for` statement. I.e. the `for` block will only run if `mat.GetLength(0) < mat.GetLength(1)`.

Comment: @TimS. yes, you're right, guess my brain is wired to see that as code stink, anything that is more than one line to me belongs in brackets.

Comment: So simple...Thank you :) I tried that before, only that I moved the "Random rnd = new Random();" also inside the first loop, giving me the same numbers on each row :(

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your list of numbers outside the for loop. This means that it's not restarted after each row.

```
static void InitMatrix(int[,] mat) {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if(mat.GetLength(0)< mat.GetLength(1))
        {
            List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 45).ToList();
            for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count );
                mat[i, j] = numbers[index];
                numbers.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code is untested, but it should work.